# Cloudformation : UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS stuck issue

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a CFN stack which is stuck in UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE_CLEANUP_IN_PROGRESS status.
It happens to me very often especially when I use a custom function.

I have read through almost everything there is but couldn't find anything that suggests a solution apart from contacting AWS support. Is there a work around to fix this or possibly dodge it altogether?

It goes back to failed status on its own after like half a day which is just too long. And writing to AWS support take at least 2 hours to get it unstuck. Please help

Comment: What resources for the failure?

Comment: When you say "custom function" do you really mean "custom resource"? If yes, it's almost certainly because the custom resource implementation is not properly signalling CloudFormation when invoked for the rollback. Verify that you're handling all possible execution conditions.

Comment: @Parsifal it is indeed my custom resource. How do make it not break rollback

Answer (score 2):

Your custom resource is not telling CloudFormation that it has successfully deleted.

To fix this, you can make the call yourself - it's just an HTTP call.

Look up the event that called the Delete operation on the stack in the CloudWatch logs.

Then extract the correct values in order to make a HTTP call to the CloudFormation server like this:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: ''' -X PUT -d '{
"Status": "SUCCESS",
"PhysicalResourceId": "<value from event>",
"StackId": "value from event, e.g. arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:111122223333:stack/awsexamplecloudformation/33ad60e0-5f25-11e9-a734-0aa6b80efab2
",
"RequestId": "value from event, e.g. e2fc8f5c-0391-4a65-a645-7c695646739",
"LogicalResourceId": "value from event, e.g.CloudWatchtrigger"
}' 'ResponseURL, e.g. https://cloudformation-custom-resource-response-useast1.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/arn%3Aaws%3Acloudformation%3Aus-east-1%3A1%3Astack/awsexamplecloudformation/33ad60e0-5blablabla'
```

For the URL, use the `ResponseURL` parameter in the Delete command.

Once you make that call, the resource should go to the `DELETE_COMPLETE` state.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-lambda-resource-delete/